# Android bluetooth connect asks for permission to access SIM. Why?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm developing a game that has 'play via bluetooth' mode. Two game instances connect to each other perfectly, but from time to time (one out of ten or so) I got a confirmation dialog on my Galaxy S3 with message that "Remote app requests permission to access SIM".

This message appears when my game tries to connect to the S3 phone but usually it happens after several successful connections.

I've tested this behavior on my Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.1) and HTC Legend (Android 2.2).
The game is using generated UUID for creating secure bluetooth connection.

Why am I getting this "access SIM"?

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Does anybody know anything about such problem or am I alone in this boat?